# GMSH extrusion with dilation

Tags: mesh, gmsh

I want to create a structured mesh with boundary layers over an rather complex geometry in GMSH. For this reason I need to seperate my geometry to smaller portions, one of them is pictured:[image: goal geometry]

Since structured meshes can only be created by extrusion, i would like to know wether it is possible to extrude a rectangle with a dilation, or if there is any other workaround known to generate a similar shape with a structured mesh.

Answer (score 0):

In gmsh structured meshs can also be generated with the 'transfinite' commands.
See examples/simple_geo/hex.geo in the gmsh installation directory for an example.